# Syncing folders where multiple files are partially changed

Tags: rsync, remote, file-copy, synchronization

I have following directory structure on remote machine

```
 ALLLibs/LibA/LibA.1
 ALLLibs/LibA/LibA.2
 ALLLibs/LibB/LibB.1
 ALLLibs/LibB/LibB.4
```

for info LibA.1 and LibA.2 are version of a directory, content of this two folder may be almost same and there can be more such folders.

I want to sync ***AllLibs*** to my other machine where network is too slow.
and Only Available option is via network

I know `rsync` is best for syncing files but I believe it does 1-1 mapping of files and sync them.

One use case I have is  `ALLLibs/LibA/LibA.1` if is synced on my other machine already and later on `ALLLibs/LibA/LibA.2` gets created on remote, I want the sync to be happened via patch of the previous lib.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the sync to be clever enough to detect similar *binary* files and only transmit the difference? `rsync` cannot do this I believe, since it works on file-by-file basis. However, incremental compressed backups may be exactly what you want: They create a compressed difference of a previous snapshot. You could automate the creation, transmission and extraction of such an archive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using rsync `-z` to compress over the network.
Other options to consider are `-H` (hardlinks) and `-S` (sparse files).

Before you run your rsync, do a version with `-nv` which does no 
updates but shows you which files will be updated.

Out of the list of files, use your knowledge to match where a 
missing file might already exist on the remote, and then
login to the remote and copy these files first.

For example, `-nv` might show updates needed for:

```
ALLLibs/LibA/LibA.2
ALLLibs/LibA/LibA.2/file1
```

but if you know it is probably a copy of `../LibA.1/file1`, then
write a script to create and populate LibA.2 from LibA.1, and
run it on the remote.  It can be as simple as `cp -rp`.  When you
do the real rsync, similar files will already be there, and changed
files will be updated. You will need `--delete` to remove files
that should not be there (be careful with this option: test with `-n` first).

Be careful in your copy command on the remote: copying a file usually sets
a new timestamp on the new file. rsync by default compares size and timestamp.
If they differ, the file will be updated. Use rsync option `-c` to instead 
checksum each file to see if it differs.